# Cannot find authenticationScheme within httpTransport

Tags: wcf, silverlight, authentication, service

I am trying to use Windows Authentication for a service and have read several posts just saying I need to add

```
httpTransport = authenticationScheme="Negotiate"
```

However I just get the message 'The authenicationScheme attribute is not declared'

Can anybody explain how I may find this, or if there is another way to give Windows Authentication to a custom service.

```
<customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_AFDiscoveryService">
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpTransport  authenticationScheme="Negotiate" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
              </binding>
        </customBinding>
```

Many Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

That should work just fine. Where do you get this message?

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_AFDiscoveryService">
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpTransport  authenticationScheme="Negotiate" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="Host.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_AFDiscoveryService" contract="Host.IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/Host/Service1/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```